# How do I "score" the JLPT practice test?

Tags: discussion

I'm considering taking the JLPT N5 test, after a few years of part-time study with a tutor. I'm currently studying GENKI II.

I took the JLPT practice today, and got 10 of 15 correct. Is there any way to tell whether that is equivalent to a passing score?

I don't really understand the JLPT scoring system, and I realize this is just the practice test. But am I ready to take the test if I got 10 out of 15 on the practice test?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](https://japanese-bank.com/info-for-businessowner-recruiter/jlpt-n5/), JLPT N5 consists of

- Reading (120) and
- Listening (60),

so that the full score is 180.
The passing score is 80 overall with reading > 38 and listening > 19.

So if you can score 2/3 on practice tests consistently, you may have a good chance of passing it.

---

[This](https://www.jlpt.jp/topics/202011051597200631.html) seems to be the official description (passing score is not mentioned).